# Sending data to Restful WCF service using ExtJS

Tags: wcf, extjs, extjs4.2

This is how my WCF service is defined to authenticate a user:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string validateUser(string username, string password);
```

It simply returns "Validated" or "NotValidated" as result.

And my ExtJS code is:

```
function loginclick(btn) {
                    var form = mainPanel.getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        var userget = Ext.getCmp('txtuser').value;
                        var passget = Ext.getCmp('txtpass').value;
                        var myparams = { 'username': userget, 'password': passget };

                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/validateUser',
                            params: Ext.encode(myparams),                              
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: this.header || { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
                            success: function (response, options) {
                                var s = response.responseText;
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', s);

                            },
                            failure: function (response, options) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Unable to get');
                            }

                        });
                    }

                }
```

When i click on the login button, I get bad request(400) error. My service is not in the same solution. When I post the data to an aspx form in the same solution it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
                             Ext.Ajax.request({
                             url: 'http://yourdomain:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/validateUser?username='+userget+'&password='+passget,
                             params: Ext.encode(myparams),                              
                             method: 'GET',
                             headers: this.header || { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
                            success: function (response, options) {
                                var s = response.responseText;
                                 Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', s);

                             },
                             failure: function (response, options) {
                                 Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Unable to get');

                         }

                     });
```

Can you fetch the params from the url?

Comment: Sorry for replying late as it was late night here when you posted the answer. It worked well enough. The only thing I changed is instead of "GET" I had to use "POST". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without encoding?

try

```
params: {

'username': userget,
'password': passget

}
```

Why do you have two times the params config?

You shouldn't use Ext.getCmp instead use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myXtype[itemId=myItemId]')[0]; http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

or

define the service in a manner that the call to it would be fullfilled like

```
string validateUser();
```

then inside the service do something similar to:

```
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
```

Like in java

Comment: Same error:"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/validateUser". But this time the messagebox displayed "Unable to get".

Comment: Hi, I tried without specifying parameters in service declaration and implementation and I could hit the service. Still I am unable to read the parameters. The situation is that I need to pass parameters as I don't know where else this service is going to be used.